# Удобный способ работы со сложными данными

Tags: jquery, массивы, json

Здравствуйте. Я только начал обучаться работе с Jquery, и ищу удобный способ (альтернативу написанию своих функций) работы с данными. А именно мне необходимо решить следующую задачу: имеется исходная переменная, хранящая в себе присланную с сервера коллекцию объектов типа {"ID":"1A-45-3L","Name":"Sys-45-4D","VendorP":"Intel"}. Необходимо сформировать на стороне клиента новую переменную такого же типа, на основе имеющейся, т.е. пользователь натыкивает на элементах управления, по сути, правила фильтрации, а код реагирует и формирует на лету новую коллекцию.

Мне интересно как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Мало информации, но мне кажется Вам нужен jQuery.extend, чтобы "сформировать на стороне клиента новую переменную такого же типа, на основе имеющейся".

Comment: Ваш вопрос мне не совсем ясен. Попробую разобраться: на клиент приходит JSON, содержащий Массив Объектов. И используя этот массив надо отобразить список фильтров (само напрашивается) и, после действий пользователя, сформировать новый массив для отправки на сервер? Приведите код клиента посмотреть (интересует сама форма).

Comment: html разметка
    <input type="checkbox" name="ProcessorVendor"  id="Intel" class="configurator"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ProcessorVendor"  id="AMD" class="configurator"/>   
    <table id="tb_listID"/>   
Скрипты:
 $(document).ready(function () {
         var DataBase;
         $.getJSON("/Platform/Platforms", null, getPlatform);
         function getPlatform(platform) { DataBase = platform;printTable(DataBase); }
         function printTable(platform) {//вывод в таблицу списка});
         
$(".configurator").on('click', function () {//сформировать новый список и вывести в таблицу}

Comment: К сожалению не могу в более понятной форме написать код клиента и скрипты. Но суть надеюсь ясна. 
после нажатия на чекбоксы - происходит фильтрация существующего списка, затем он выводится в таблицу. С сервером, после получения изначального списка, обмен данными больше не происходит.

Comment: @WonderfulFalcon добавляйте код к вопросу в таких случаях.

Comment: Прошу прощения за неправильно оформленный вопрос. В следующий раз сделаю все по уму.

Comment: @WonderfulFalcon а что вам мешает его отредактировать ?

Comment: @Lucky спасибо за совет. Это похоже именно то что мне нужно.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <script src="./jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          /*
            получаем список и строим по нему форму #myform и таблицу
            элементы списка:
              [{
                "ID": "1A-45-3L",
                "Name":"Sys-45-4D",
                "VendorP":"Intel" //как я понял это для фильтров
              }, ....]
          */

          var filters = {}, withoutFilters = {};
          /*(function (arr) {
            arr.forEach(function (obj) {
              withoutFilters[obj.VendorP] = true;
            });
          }(arrayOfObjectsFromServer));*/
          $('input[type=checkbox]', '#myform').click(function getFiltersValues () {
            // После каждого клика по checkbox заново полностью строим таблицу. TODO:                 оптимизировать это дело
            //buildTable();
            filters = {};
            $('input[type=checkbox]', '#myform').filter(':checked').each(function (i, checkbox) {
              filters[checkbox.value] = true;
            });
            Object.keys(filters).length || (filters = withoutFilters) // Если в фильтрах ничего не выделено, то показуем все что есть.
            $('tr', '#mytable').each(function (i, tr) {
              /*Если значения атрибута 'data-vendor' нету в filters, то удаляем эту         строку*/
              if (!($(tr).attr('data-vendor') in filters)) {
                $(tr).remove();
              }
            });

          });
        });
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <form id='myform'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ProcessorVendor" value="Intel"                 class="configurator"/>Intel<br><!-- Поменял id на value.-->
        <input type="checkbox" name="ProcessorVendor" value="AMD" class="configurator"/>AMD<br>
      </form>
      <table id="mytable">
        <tr data-vendor="Intel">
          <td>Intel</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-vendor="Intel">
          <td>Intel</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-vendor="AMD">
          <td>AMD</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: По сути тут новый список создавать и не надо. Если что не так, обращайтесь.

Comment: Посмотрите еще на эту штуку: http://angularjs.org/ Покруче, но и посложнее, jquery будет.

Comment: @alexandrr спасибо за ответы и советы! Буду тестировать и разбираться!

Comment: @alexandrr как-то странно противопоставлять angular и jquery :) это что-то вроде как противопоставление башенного крана и кирпичей.

Comment: @eicto В этом конкретном случае, все то, что я реализовал на jquery, на angular, смею предположить (поверхностно ознакомился), выглядело бы куда лучше и проще. Но тут, опят таки, надо разбираться с краном. А кирпичи как то попроще будут)))

Comment: это... я как-бы мягко намекаю, что во первых jquery не фреймворк, во вторых, использование angular не противоречит использованию jquery, я-бы сказал [даже так](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/bower.json)

    {
      "name": "AngularJS",
      "devDependencies": {
        "jquery": "1.10.2",
        //....
      }
    }

Comment: @eicto Намек понял. Перечитал свой первый коммент про angular и осознал что некорректно выразился. Я рассматривал jquery и angular не как библиотеку и фреймворк, а как два инструмента, каждый из которых заслуживает внимания.
Надо было бы так: "Посмотрите еще на эту штуку: http://angularjs.org/ Для общего развития."

Comment: ну, да только один инструмент из другого сделан :)